# How do I add some text in front of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text-area and I want to put something like a div or a floating text in front of it and when someone click that text I want to open a link in a new window. I searched for it on Google, but I couldn't find a way to do that using HTML/CSS.

Here is the CSS code for `textarea`:

```
textarea {  
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px; 
    margin-top:-200px; 
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:green;
    background-image: url("../Pictures/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. You can start by changing the title to something much shorter and more descriptive instead of a copy of your complete question

Comment: i searched on site  then my question was copied as title ... sorry

Comment: what is the id/class you're using for this CSS? I'd try `<a href="Link" id="idName"></a>`

Comment: i used id="texta" ,i just tryed your solution , it worked thank you :)

Comment: No problem. I submitted it as a question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code.

```
<a href="Link" id="idName"></a>
```

Also, I'd practice using all lower cases in your directories. I.e "pictures" not "Pictures". Just easier to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can to formalize link.

```
    a {
   display:block;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background: url ('your pic');
   outline: none;
   ...your fantasy.
}
```

If you need to resize this text-area, it's would be another question.